# Wrong value for window.innerWidth during onload event in Firefox for Android?

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox, default

Okay, so, the problem I am facing is this: my mobile Firefox browser is not retrieving the correct values for `window.innerWidth`, `document.documentElement.clientWidth`, or even the width of a `div` styled to take up the whole client window after page load.

I am not crazy, my code works just fine in every other browser! For some reason Firefox initializes these values with defaults and then gets the correct values later on. If at any point I interrupt my JavaScript with an `alert()`, these properties magically become accurate afterwards.

I have scoured the internet for an answer and all I can find is a hack workaround: use `window.setTimeout` to delay the use of these properties until they have time to populate correctly. That is crazy! Users want speed, not an extra delay just to view my site on a Firefox browser.

What I don't understand is that I can set a `div` up to fill the client window perfectly before the values become accurate. I do this in css by setting width and height of my div's id to 100%. `document.documentElement` is basically the same as `document.getElementById("my_div");` after all the document elements have loaded, so, how does the browser know how  big the `div` should be when it doesn't have the correct dimensions of the client window in the first place?

I have tried running my code inside a `window.addEventListener("load",function(event_){ //My Code });` but still these values will not generate. Is there a page load event that comes after `window.onload`?

If anyone can tell me why only Firefox mobile seems to display this odd behavior I will give you a mental high five.

Here's a bit of sample code for recreating the problem:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- Added " after javascript during edit. -->
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.addEventListener("load",function(event_){
                var output=document.getElementById("output");
                /* Returns some default value like 980. */
                output.innerHTML=window.innerWidth;

                alert("After this alert, the value will change.");
                /* Returns an accurate value like 511. */
                output.innerHTML=window.innerWidth;
            });
        </script>
        <!-- Added title during edit. -->
        <title>Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p id="output">Default Output</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

My Firefox for android version is 35.0.1. My Android version is 4.4.4. On my device, Firefox displays "980" in the output p element, shows the alert, and then displays "980" again. After page refresh, the first two steps remain the same, but the output after the alert changes to 360. This happens with `document.documentElement.clientWidth` as well. No properties I try seem to get the correct values. It seems that Firefox has some sort of delay after page load before it has access to the client window's dimensions...

I tried the verge.airve.com plugin without JQuery and its initial feedback remained at 980. It also initialized as 980 on Chrome, which was weird, because Chrome worked as expected without it...

After much debate a solution was found! Firefox apparently resizes the window after it is loaded (I guess for good measure, who really knows)! So, by adding a resize event handler in addition to window.onload, this problem can be averted! See accepted answer below for more details.

Comment: Can you use the resize event instead of load?

Comment: You aren't crazy, you haven t worked with IE5 !

Comment: can't repro FF35.0.1 for  android 4.4.4

Comment: Okay, I edited the code a bit, it should work (or not work) now if you just copy and paste that into an html file and run it. I'm testing on a Moto G and my android version is 4.4.4. What I am seeing here is the value remains default before and after the `alert` is called. After page refresh it initializes at 980 for the default and after the `alert` goes down to 360.

Comment: I have tried the "resize" event listener, but it doesn't fire without an orientation change. My Firefox version is also 35.0.1. In regards to my question title... Well, I figured catchy would get results. \=) Seriously, though, this dilemma is making me crazy. Surely other people know of a workaround that is legit.

Comment: Do you use jQuery on the page? just to give you the code answer in $()

Comment: I do not. I literally copied and pasted the code you see into an html file and ran it on my phone's browser. I would like to steer clear of JQuery for something as simple as getting client dimensions, but you can throw answers at me in JQuery. It's technically still Javascript, right? \=)

Comment: Here is an article on this topic http://tripleodeon.com/2011/12/first-understand-your-screen/

Comment: Ha ha, oh, man. The article is basically saying there is no standard or workaround. I would basically have to use a different method to support each browser... It also concludes in the summary that there is sometimes a delay before properties become available even after page load. I assume this refers to my problem with Firefox... Such a bittersweet realization. The article is 4 years old, of course, and I have read it before. Is there really still no standard?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Make sure your measurement is done when whole document is loaded and resized.

```js
window.onload = showViewport;
window.onresize = showViewport;

function showViewport() {
  var output=document.getElementById("output");
  var width = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth, window.innerWidth || 0);
  var height= Math.max(document.documentElement.clientHeight, window.innerHeight || 0)
  output.innerHTML = "Viewport size is " + width + "x" + height;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <p id="output">Default Output</p>
</body>
```

Comment: Sweet! Apparently in Firefox the "resize" event fires last, which is strange. Your code does return the correct size of the viewport inside the resize Event, but resize doesn't fire at all on other browsers... I didn't need to use `Math.max`, just `document.documentElement`.

Comment: Actually, this works pretty nicely for all of my browsers! I do think it's strange that Firefox fires that resize event after window.load, but I guess my page will have to have a resize event handler anyway. This works nicely even when resizing the viewport with a meta tag! Thank you very much!

Comment: document.documentElement.clientWidth is more accurate for me somehow

Answer (score 1):

The problem (innerWidth === 980) persists for Firefox 40.0 under Android 4.4.4. A 1 msec wait is a circumvention. Replace

```
window.onload = myProgram;
```

by

```
 window.onload = function() {setTimeout(myProgram, 1)};
```

In the meantime I encountered this problem while adapting a fairly elaborate site to small screens. Firefox obeys the CSS following "@media only screen and (max-width: 768px)". However, when one tries to set event handlers depending on device widths, Firefox fails miserably. I needed the above trick with 0.5 second wait at all spots where I picked up the device width. This wait time was necessary for Nexus 7 (2012), but who knows what is needed for other devices?

Answer (score 1):

```
window.setTimeout(yourFunction, 1);
```

This did the job for me, 1ms is enough.

Comment: This worked for me, too.  This statement actually executes the function after the delay, so you don't need to window.onload it too.  The delay that worked for me was 85ms; below that figure, the browser made up wildly inaccurate dimensions for both the width and height of the <div> (Google Chrome).

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm the issue, for example in Firefox 38.0.1 on Android 4.1.2. Created a [js bin](http://jsbin.com/bizeze/2/) for testing purposes.

I'd like to check window.innerWidth for custom DOM manipulations on different resolutions (mobile, tablet and desktop size), so it'd be important to get the correct window.innerWidth value already in the document.ready() state and not just only in the window.load().

```js
$('#inline').html($(window).width());

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#ready').html(window.innerWidth);
});

$(window).load(function() {
  $('#load').html(window.innerWidth);
});

setTimeout(function() {
  $('#setTimeout').html(window.innerWidth);
}, 1000);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  
  <p><span id="inline"></span></p>
  <p>$(document).ready(): <span id="ready"></span></p>
  <p>$(window).load(): <span id="load"></span></p>
  <p>setTimeout(1000): <span id="setTimeout"></span></p>
  
</body>
</html>
```

(I wanted to add only a comment, and not answer, but no reputations yet to do so :-)

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue while using `BrowserComponent` in `CodeNameOne` and Android

My solution was to put the js inside a function like so

```
function runScripts()
{
    //get width here
}
```

And listen to the `onLoad` event of the `BrowserComponent` to execute this script once the browser has been fully loaded

like so:

```
    BrowserComponent browser = new BrowserComponent();
    browser.addWebEventListener("onLoad", new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            browser.execute("runScripts()");
        }
    });
    browser.setURL("http://www.URL.com");
```

Handling `window.onload` in the html wasn't enough to wait for the appropriate width to be served

Besides this solution I also found that `window.setTimeout(runScripts, 500);` works to get the right document width, at the expense of wasting half a second

Comment: I have since started using document.documentElement.clientWidth and clientHeight to get the dimensions of my inner window. It works great in Chrome, although I can't speak for Firefox as I haven't tested in Firefox for a while.

Answer (score 0):

A very hack solution I found is to invoke a fake link in the header.  My guess is the time delay allows updating of window.innerWidth and window.innerHeight prior to script execution.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/fake.css"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, getting varying width when fetching window.innerWidth on an android device with Firefox. I tried some of the suggestions above, but without success - possibly implementing the examples in a wrong way?

However, by using the code below, I got a system that seems to be working 100% as far as I have tested. It also makes little delay as it break the loop as soon as it get a stable result.

```
var canvasWidth = 0;
var canvasHeight = 0;
    
var previousWidth = -1;
var previousHeight = -1;

while ((canvasWidth != previousWidth) || (canvasHeight != previousHeight))
{
  previousWidth  = canvasWidth;
  previousHeight = canvasHeight;
 
  canvasWidth  = window.innerWidth;
  canvasHeight = window.innerHeight;
}
```